# How do I loop through a single data frame column to count how many different values there are?

Tags: python, pandas

Im new to python and was wondering how i would go about looping through all values in my dates column and counting how many different dates there are within it in total.

I know it is possible to do this by using the .nunique() function but i am looking for how to do this using a For loop.

my data frame is simply a table with 1 column of different dates. within my actual data i have over 500 different rows so i have cut it down to just 10 for this. For this example i expect the result to be 4.

```
date_tbl

Index    Date
0        07/08/2015
1        07/08/2015
2        07/08/2015
3        08/08/2015
4        08/08/2015
5        08/08/2015
6        08/08/2015
7        09/08/2015
8        09/08/2015
9        10/08/2015
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do this using a `for` loop, that goes against the whole idea of using pandas

Comment: You can use itertools for that as well. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use [df.unique()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html). That's why pandas is used. You are not supposed to loop through pandas.

Even for applying manipulations to the data inside dataframe you should go for df.apply().

This should get the list of unique date values as a list:

`df.Date.unique()`

In case, you want to use loop:

Use df.iterrows() :

```
def findUniqueDates(df):
    unique_dates = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Date'] not in unique_dates
        unique_date.append(row['Date'])
    return unique_dates
```

Comment: OP want `I know it is possible to do this by using the .nunique() function but i am looking for how to do this using a For loop.`

Comment: Oh thanks @jezrael for informating me. I will change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a loop, thats one possibility:

```
unique_list = []
for i,r in date_tbl.iterrows():
    if r['Date'] not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(r['Date'])

len(unique_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below unless this very much required to deal with specific case:

```
>>> df
         Date
0  07/08/2015
1  07/08/2015
2  07/08/2015
3  08/08/2015
4  08/08/2015
5  08/08/2015
6  08/08/2015
7  09/08/2015
8  09/08/2015
9  10/08/2015
```

First convert the `Date` column into datetime format:

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Now, use `np.unique` to get the results:

```
>>> print(np.unique(df["Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')))
['08-07-15' '08-08-15' '08-09-15' '08-10-15']
```

Comment: OP 1) wants number of uniques, not the array (so it would be `nunique`) 2) knows `nunique()` exists but wants to use a loop

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, I see, that's what i mentioned if there its utmost necessary to loop through otherwise it just an option , otherwise pure pythonic ways are there.